# SilverStripe custom csv/ excel export function for ModelAdmin class

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. In my project, I am trying to implement a create a way to override the ModelAdmin export the CSV function to add custom fields with the custom query that are displayed on the summary list table. There is a getExportFields() method that I can specify the custom fields. But that problem is that it is just not enough for me. Following is my scenario.

I overrode the getList() method of the custom ModelAdmin class using some custom queries based on the filter. What I need to do is that I need to export all the data that are on the list with some custom additional fields using custom queries. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share some of your code?